# Seeing the same "copy and paste" answer for multiple questions

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

I'm not sure if it is just me, but lastly I have noticed the same "copy and paste" answer for a couple of different questions given by a particular user.

For me, the answer is kind of vague and really doesn't explain much. Also, for me, it defeats the purpose of the community if you going to get some "generic" answer

Anyways, I was just wondering if this is a good reason to flag it or if there is a policy in place for stopping these copy and paste answers

Answer (score 5):

Sure, it's a good reason to flag the answer as `low-quality` answer or `in need of moderator intervention` based on the type of answer.

[image]

Once Moderators received your flag, we will take the correct action to approve or reject this flag based on the situation.

You can also raise a flag for the question itself in case it was duplicated and the same answer will solve the current OP issue.

For more details check [What are Flags? When should I flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: The link provided with **What are Flags? What do I do with flags?** not working. Please correct it.

Comment: Thank you, The URL is working, but unfortunately for only moderators, let me change it to another related link